# How to clone only properties with Object.assign?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to send a message whose content is derived from a Javascript proxy, and the `postMessage()` method fails except when I manually copy the  the properties of my proxy on a new object:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': [object Object] could not be cloned.]
```

However, if I manually assign all the fields through boilerplate code like so

```
 var b = {};
 b.myField = a.myField;
```

the postMessage works fine. What I was expecting is that the following would have worked fine too:

```
var b = Object.assign({},a);
```

but in this case it fails with the same message. Why is Object.assign cloning properties and how can I debug the cloning error?

Comment: By “JavaScript proxy”, do you mean an actual `Proxy`? Don’t use those, ever.

Comment: they come from a liibrary I am not creating them myself

Comment: What library are you using that gives you proxies?

Comment: Lightning Framework for Salesforce

Comment: I'm curious on what have you applied `postMessage()`? it could be very nice to show the whole actual code that produced the error

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with Object.assign in Lightning too. I did good, using:

```
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
```

My issue back then was, that `Object.assign({},a)` made a clone by reference and not by value. (I know this only answers the second part of your question, but maybe you can use it as a workaround so far)

I just read you are using a `Window` function. Be aware, that the window object is a wrapper object in lightning due to the [locker service](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html)

Comment: from what I have read Object.assign is supposed to do a clone by value?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 didn't work for me back then :( had to serialize it.

Comment: this is the related [SFSE Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/190746/2513)